# make span selection go to parent div

Tags: jquery

I have a span inside a div.

```
.myspan {
    float:right;
}
<div>john, doe                    <span class="myspan">(male)</span></div>
```

Is there a way if the user clicks or hovers over the span I can make those events go to the parent div?

Comment: events go to the parent div means???

Comment: these divs are inside the ajax autocomplete list. What is happening is if the user selects the span the autocomplete does not know the div was selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events bubble up to the parent element by default. You don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the parent, you can always say

```
(this).parent();
```

but i am not clear what is your requirement

as Matti said , by default events propogates to parent...

read this

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/